# Алгоритм случайного числа на С

Tags: c, алгоритм

Как организовать алгоритм случайного числа для массива 10*10 так, чтобы элементы этого массива имели как отрицательные, так и положительные значения? (на си)

Answer (score 1):

Если устраивает диапазон от -RAND_MAX/2...0...RAND_MAX/2, то просто вычитаете из результата random() RAND_MAX/2. А далее отмасштабировать результат до -N...0...N не проблема.

Comment: а как это организовать в программе? вот там идет запись ... srand(time(NULL));
for (i=0;i<10;i++) 
for (j=0;j<10;j++) 
arr[i][j]=rand()%100; /*это я так поняла означает что диапазон выбора значений от 0 до 100, а как записать здесь от -50 до 50 например?*/

Comment: Ну, вычтите 50 =) Получится от -50 до 50: (0 - 50) до (100 - 50).

Comment: эээ...тогда я задам вопрос так =)(извините, я просто новичок) вот rand()%100; , что означают скобки и почему они пустые, и что означает знак %?

Comment: В скобках пишутся аргументы функции. Ну, как sin(0) - синус нуля. abs(10) - модуль 10. Для функции rand аргументы не нужны, вот скобки и пустые. Знак процента - получение остатка от деления. По определению rand вернёт любое по величине число (от 0 до максимально возможного для типа int) и чтоб привести его к определённому диапазону надо получить остаток от деления на этот диапазон. про это, пожалуйста, почитайте учебник.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное! ^^

Comment: To @vinnypaf. Если Ваш компилятор позволяет, используйте random() вместо rand().